# Interpolation of missing values in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to fill down the missing values using Pentaho pdi.

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Found so far only [Filling data gaps in a stream in Pentaho Data Integration, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040054/filling-data-gaps-in-a-stream-in-pentaho-data-integration-is-it-possible/26049521) but it fills in with the last known value.

Potentially, I thought I could work with the above solution, I also added the next amount to the analytical query, along with the next date. Then, I added the flag in the clone step and filter the original results from the input into Dummy and generated results (from the calculator) to a calculator (at the moment). Then, potentially, I can dump that separate stream to a temp table in a database and run the sql query which will do the rolling subtraction. I am also investigating the javascript step.

I disregarded the Python or R Executor step because at the end I will be running the job on the aws vm and I already foresee the pain I will go through with the installation.

What would be your suggestions? Is there a simple way to do interpolation?

Updated for the question
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method provided in your link does work from my testing, (I am using `LAG` instead of `LEAD` for your tasks though). Here I am not looking to replicate that method, just another option for you by using JavaScript to build the logic which you might also extend to other applications:

In the testing below (tested on PDI-8.0), the transformation has 5 steps, see below

[image]

1. **Data Grid** step to create testing data with three fields: `date`, `account number` and `amount`
2. **Sort rows** to sort the rows based on `account number` and `date`. this is required for `Analytic Query` step, if your source data are already sorted, then skip this step
3. **Analytic Query** step, see below, create two more fields: `prev_date` and `prev_amount`

[image]

4. **Modified Java Script Value** step, add the following code, nothing else is needed to configure in this step:

   ```
   var days_diff = dateDiff(prev_date, date, "d")

   if (days_diff > 0) {
       /* retrieve index for two fields: 'date', 'amount' 
        * and modify their values accordingly
        */
       var idx_date = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue("date")
       var idx_amount = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue("amount")

       /* amount to increment by each row */
       var delta_amount = (amount - prev_amount)/days_diff

       for (var i = 1; i < days_diff; i++) {
           newRow = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
           newRow[idx_date]   = dateAdd(prev_date, "d", i);
           newRow[idx_amount] = prev_amount + delta_amount * i;
           putRow(newRow);
       } 
   }
   ```
5. **Select values** step to remove unwanted fields, i.e.: prev_date, prev_amount

Run the transformation, you will have the following shown under the `Preview data` tab of  `Modified Java Script Value` step:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Per your comments, you can do the following, assume you have a new field `account_type`:

1. in **Analytic Query** step, add a new field `prev_account_type`, similar to two other prev_ fields, just from different `Subject`: *account_type*
2. in **Modified Java Script Value** step, you need to retrieve the Row index for account_type and modify the logic to compute delta_amount, so when `prev_account_type` is not the same as the current `account_type`, the delta_amount is ZERO, see below code:

   ```
   var days_diff = dateDiff(prev_date, date, "d")

   if (days_diff > 0) {
       /* retrieve index for three fields: 'date', 'amount', 'account_type' */
       var idx_date     = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue("date")
       var idx_amount   = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue("amount")
       var idx_act_type = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue("account_type")

       /* amount to increment by each row */
       var delta_amount = prev_account_type.equals(account_type) ? (amount - prev_amount)/days_diff : 0;

       /* copy the current Row into newRow and modify fields accordingly */
       for (var i = 1; i < days_diff; i++) {
           newRow = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
           newRow[idx_date]     = dateAdd(prev_date, "d", i);
           newRow[idx_amount]   = prev_amount + delta_amount * i;
           newRow[idx_act_type] = prev_account_type;
           putRow(newRow);
       } 
   }
   ```

**Note:** invoking Javascript interpreter does have some performance hit, so if that matters to you, stick to the method in the link you provided.

Comment: Hi @jxc, it is just perfect! Question, though, If I got a few columns I need to interpolate...If I are to add logic to your js, do I use &&?

Comment: @eponkratova, I think for more columns, just retrieve their index using `getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(COL_NAME)`, find the delta to increase on each newRow. then set their value with `newRow[idx] = ...`, all other fields are copied into newRow otherwise. There is no need to use `&&`.  make sure to set their prev_ values through the `Analytic Query` step.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and message you later. Just one more question, if I need to do the interpolation by account_number and product type - let's assume that I have one more column which says product type. How should I handle it? Add the product type along with the account number in the analytical query? How will your formula work for the account 0234051 > product type 31?

Comment: Continue - nitially, it had the 'start date' of 2/1/2019 and the amount of 8900 but then, the account changed the product type to 134 on 4/5/2019 and the amount of 117000. Although 4/5/2019 is the 'end date' but 117000 is not the end amount because it is a completely different product type for the same account. What should be populated instead between 2/1/2019 and 4/5/2019 is 8900.

Comment: @eponkratova, if you add both account_number and account_type into the `Group field` in the `Analytic Query` step. there will be no interpolation between  2/1/2019 and 4/5/2019 since they are in two different groups. what are you expected results?

Comment: In the example above, I would expect 8900 filled in every row between 2/1/2019 and 4/5/2019. Do I need to do something like - run your job. For the case like I gave to you, there will be empty rows - if my understanding is correct - so, I filter the resulted dataset into null and not null. Those that have null, I just fill down with the prev value. Then, I will append the streams. Does it make sense?

Comment: @eponkratova, this will need some adjustment on the JS code. If 1/2/2019 in the same account/type combo is 8000 (instead of 8900), you still want 8900 instead of extrapolation, correct? I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: 8900 is just an example. And yes, what I need is whatever amount was on 2/1/2019 - this example. It is similar to the simple filldown method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192853/discussion-between-eponkratova-and-jxc).